# Split string and put it to list in Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, arraylist

I read a html page and put that in StringBuilder , How can I split that with multiple character ">","<","/" ...

```
String[] objData = str.toString().split("<");
```

after that how can I get length of objData ?

Comment: You can get the length of objData by calling objData.length :) 
By the way there are better tools for parsing html in Java.

Answer (score 2):

replace your all characters you what to split with a new character and then split it

String[] objData =   str.replace("<", ">").replace("/", ">").split(">");

Answer (score -1):

You could use SAX-Parser to parse the XML or have a look at [XMLPullParser](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html) coming with Android:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html